# Swing in Java Netbeans limitations

Tags: java, swing

How many Swing (`button`, `text field`, `label`, etc) can I use in Java NetBeans because I have 700+ swing in my project and when I run the program it says `Error: can't load main class.`

Comment: please post the full stack trace of your program.

Comment: I don't think the error relates to the number of components you have, it relates to how your project is setup

Comment: for the error Could not find or load main class, it is a path issue, swing has nothing to do with that, try to take a help from this url -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean